# Integration of Spengo with Java Jersey Rest Api having tomcat server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, kerberos, jersey-2.0

We are planning to build Spengo authentication with Java Jersey Rest Api with a tomcat server. I couldn't find proper blogs regarding this integration.

Kindly suggest any working blogs without Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

SPNEGO is available out-of-the-box through the [`SpnegoAuthenticator`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#SPNEGO_Valve). In order to enable it you need to:

1. Set `SPNEGO` as authentication method in your `web.xml` descriptor:

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

2. Set up the required `conf/krb5.ini` and `conf/jaas.conf` as described in the [Windows Authentication How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html).
3. Add some security contraints. This can be done in two ways:

   - You can add `<security-contraint>`s in your `web.xml` file, which give users access based on a combination of HTTP method and URL pattern (see [Securing Web Applications](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/security-webtier002.html#GKBAA)),
   - If you need a more fine-grained control, you can inject a `SecurityContext` to your JAX-RS methods: see [Programmatic Security](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter15/programmatic_security.html).